# Why does my bitmap save a jpg with black bars on either side?

Tags: c#, forms, panel, image, jpeg

My program has a splitcontainer within the form. Panel1 has a button that when clicked should save panel2 as a picture (ideally a jpg). I have a couple problems with the code I'm using.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(splitContainer1.Panel2.Width * 2, splitContainer1.Panel2.Height);
        splitContainer1.Panel2.DrawToBitmap(bmp, splitContainer1.Panel2.Bounds);
        bmp.Save(@"C:\Test.jpg",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

Here are the issues with my code that I'm curious about.

1. if I use it as is, I get a jpg file saved out correctly but it contains additional black around the sides.[image]
2. If I change the last line of code to omit System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg I get a picture with two clear boxes on either side which is still not what I want. (They're clear but they are still there).
   [image]

How can I get just the jpg file saved without the extra area around the panel?

EDIT:
Several people have pointed out my call of Splitcontainer1.panel2.width * 2. If I do not multiply the width by two I only get half of the actual panel2 like below, and it still has the unwanted blackbars/clearbars:
[image]

Comment: Is the output, by chance, twice as big as it should be due to the black/clear blocks?

Comment: Chris is correct.  To answer the second part of the question, you get black bars vs clear bars because default is probably PNG, which allows an alpha channel (transparency) whereas JPG contains no alpha channel.

Comment: why would it be a png if my code tells it to be a jpg?

Comment: Did you try the second piece of code in my answer?  You need to specify the bounds correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are explicitly making the Bitmap too wide:

```
splitContainer1.Panel2.Width * 2
```

Just make it:

```
splitContainer1.Panel2.Width
```

Also, you are specifying the bounds incorrectly.  they represent the rectangle *within the bitmap* to draw in.  Your call should probably be:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(splitContainer1.Panel2.Width, splitContainer1.Panel2.Height);
splitContainer1.Panel2.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0,0,splitContainer1.Panel2.Bounds.Width,splitContainer1.Panel2.Bounds.Height));
```

Comment: Perfect. I noted my reason for making the width twice the size but it appears I was, as you pointed out, setting the bounds incorrectly. Adjusted and it works fine now. Thanks!